# How to fill database from buttonclick

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, button, model-view-controller

I have a database which i would like to `fill` with a filler-`method`. I wish to call on this `method` from the `Index`-view in my `MVC`-project. I have tested that the `method` works by running it each time the `index.cshtml` is run, and it fills the `table`. The only problem with this is that if I `refresh` the `index`-page, the `table` gets filled with the exact same `data` once again. Which results in me getting two of every item.

So I have come to the conclusion that I want to bind my `filler()-method` to a button on the index-page to fill the `table`. My question is then:

How do I directly bind a method to a button in my `project`?

Extra info:
The filler-method is in its own class called DBFiller.cs, and when I set it to run on index launch I added DBfiller.filler() in the `actionresult` of my `controller`.

Code:
DBFiller.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Oblig1.BLL;
using Oblig1.Model;
using Oblig1.DAL;

namespace Oblig1
{
public class DBFiller
{
    public void Filler()
    {
        var userDb = new UserBLL();
        var itemDb = new ItemBLL();

        var city1 = new Cities();
        var city2 = new Cities();
        var city3 = new Cities();

        city1.Cityname = "Oslo";
        city1.Postcode = "9382";

        city2.Cityname = "Trondheim";
        city2.Postcode = "2301";

        city3.Cityname = "Bergen";
        city3.Postcode = "1723";

        var user1 = new Users()
        {
            Address = "Moroveien 7",
            Firstname = "Martin",
            Surname = "Hermansen",
            Email = "mh@mh.no",
            Password = "mhmhmh",
            Phonenr = "93929392",
            Postcode = "9382",
            cities = city1
        };

        var user2 = new Users()
        {
            Address = "Bakvendtgata 8",
            Firstname = "Hanne",
            Surname = "Lande",
            Email = "hl@hl.no",
            Password = "hlhlhl",
            Phonenr = "82711212",
            Postcode = "2301",
            cities = city2
        };

        var user3 = new Users()
        {
            Address = "Fisefin Aveny 14",
            Firstname = "Voldemort",
            Surname = "Olsen",
            Email = "vo@vo.no",
            Password = "vovovo",
            Phonenr = "12672891",
            Postcode = "1723",
            cities = city3
        };

        var item1 = new Items()
        {
            Currentstock = 40,
            Itemname = "Blanding",
            Itemprice = 99,
            Itemtype = "Pasta",
            PictureURL = "/img/pasta_blanding.png",
            Itemid = 78
        };

        var item2 = new Items()
        {
            Currentstock = 17,
            Itemname = "Fusilli",
            Itemprice = 119,
            Itemtype = "Pasta",
            PictureURL = "/img/pasta_fusilli.png",
            Itemid = 63
        };
        var item3 = new Items()
        {
            Currentstock = 80,
            Itemname = "Farfalle",
            Itemprice = 69,
            Itemtype = "Pasta",
            PictureURL = "/img/pasta_farfalle.png",
            Itemid = 30
        };
        var item4 = new Items()
        {
            Currentstock = 63,
            Itemname = "Colored Fusilli #1",
            Itemprice = 45,
            Itemtype = "Pasta",
            PictureURL = "/img/pasta_fusilli_farget.png",
            Itemid = 22
        };
        var item5 = new Items()
        {
            Currentstock = 3,
            Itemname = "Colored Fusilli #2",
            Itemprice = 33,
            Itemtype = "Pasta",
            PictureURL = "/img/pasta_fusilli_farget2.png",
            Itemid = 98
        };
        var item6 = new Items()
        {
            Currentstock = 77,
            Itemname = "Macaroni",
            Itemprice = 25,
            Itemtype = "Pasta",
            PictureURL = "/img/pasta_macaroni.png",
            Itemid = 76
        };
        var item7 = new Items()
        {
            Currentstock = 80,
            Itemname = "Measure",
            Itemprice = 299,
            Itemtype = "Tools",
            PictureURL = "/img/pasta_messure.png",
            Itemid = 59
        };
        var item8 = new Items()
        {
            Currentstock = 14,
            Itemname = "Multitool",
            Itemprice = 499,
            Itemtype = "Tool",
            PictureURL = "/img/pasta_multitool.png",
            Itemid = 69
        };
        var item9 = new Items()
        {
            Currentstock = 88,
            Itemname = "Penne",
            Itemprice = 19,
            Itemtype = "Pasta",
            PictureURL = "/img/pasta_penne.png",
            Itemid = 79
        };
        var item10 = new Items()
        {
            Currentstock = 45,
            Itemname = "Roller",
            Itemprice = 59,
            Itemtype = "Tool",
            PictureURL = "/img/pasta_ruller.png",
            Itemid = 79
        };
        var item11 = new Items()
        {
            Currentstock = 179,
            Itemname = "Spoon",
            Itemprice = 39,
            Itemtype = "Tool",
            PictureURL = "/img/pasta_sleiv.png",
            Itemid = 110
        };
        var item12 = new Items()
        {
            Currentstock = 17,
            Itemname = "Spagetti",
            Itemprice = 9,
            Itemtype = "Pasta",
            PictureURL = "/img/pasta_penne.png",
            Itemid = 79
        };



        itemDb.registerItem(item1);
        itemDb.registerItem(item2);
        itemDb.registerItem(item3);
        itemDb.registerItem(item4);
        itemDb.registerItem(item5);
        itemDb.registerItem(item6);
        itemDb.registerItem(item7);
        itemDb.registerItem(item8);
        itemDb.registerItem(item9);
        itemDb.registerItem(item10);
        itemDb.registerItem(item11);
        itemDb.registerItem(item12);
        userDb.setIn(user1);
        userDb.setIn(user2);
        userDb.setIn(user3);

    }

}
}
```

My attempt at adding it in the index-launcher in my User-Controller:

```
namespace Oblig1.Controllers
{
public class UserController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new UserBLL();
        var filler = new DBFiller();
        filler.Filler();
        List<Item> allItems = model.getItems();

        return PartialView(allItems);
    }
}
}
```

Index.cshtml if it helps any:

```
@using Oblig1
@model IEnumerable<Oblig1.Model.Item>
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<br />
<br />
<br />
<head>
<title>Index</title>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
</head>

@if (Model != null)
{

<div class="row">
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    { 
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="@item.pictureURL" alt="...">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>@item.itemname</h3>
                <p>Antall på lager: @item.currentstock<br />kr @item.itemprice,00</p>

                <button class="btn btn-success">@Html.ActionLink("Add to Cart", "AddToCart", new { id = item.itemid }, null)</button>




            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    }
</div>


}
```

Attempt at filler-call by JS:

```
@model IEnumerable<Oblig1.Model.Item>
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<br />
<br />
<br />
<head>
<title>Index</title>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script type="text/jscript">
$('#fill').click(function () {
    var url = "/UserController/Filler";
    $.post( url);

});
</script>

</head>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="fill" value="Fill Database"> </button>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Filler()
    {
        var filler = new DBFiller();
        filler.Filler();
        return View("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the logic of filling to another action method and call it using jquery Ajax call on the click of the button

EDIT:

Please refer the below link for sample

http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/jquery-ajax-get-and-post-calls-to.html

Basically below is the code to link the click of your button with Action method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#ButtonID').click(function () {
        var url = "/ControllerName/YourActionMethod";
        $.post( url);

    });
});
```

Add the above code in your page with appropriate url and button id

Comment: Actually never used Ajax before, could you provide some sourcecode or a link to something relevant? Thanks

Comment: I have added a link and some sample code.See if that helps.

Comment: It doesnt seem to be working, I'm probably doing something wrong tho.

Comment: Can you paste your javascript / jquery code where you are making jquery call and also your controller which has action methods

Comment: - So does the button click event works ? I mean on click of the button is  Filler method called. Also you can remove the return type for Filler action method i.e. you can keep it void Filler() and remove the return statement

Comment: I am now running a Debug.WriteLine(), inside the fillermethod to check if its getting called. But it isnt. :/

Comment: try wrapping your jquery click handler in $(document).ready.I have updated my answer .Also make sure you are not getting any javascript error.You can check it by pressing f12 in browser and going to console section.And have you included jquery in your project?

Comment: I'm actually getting two errors in the console:
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined 
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined. And yes jquery is added to my project! The first error is in the file jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js, and the second is the $ infront of (document)

Comment: try this link http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/03/various-reasons-and-solutions-of-jquery.html

Comment: I was referencing the wrong version of jquery.... but its fixed now! Now i am getting the errormessage: http://localhost:3297/UserController/Filler 404 (Not Found)